# Getting all wikipedia articles with precise time

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Some wikipedia articles has precise timestamp in infobox, like this one:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11
>
> (Launch date: July 16, 1969, 13:32:00 UTC)

or:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_Day_bombing
>
> (Date: 8 November 1987 10:43 (GMT))

Is there a way to get a list of all articles like this? Seems like it possible with SPARQL

Comment: You can have a look at the DBpedia resources and see that there is no such property extracted from the Wikipedia infobox: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apollo_11

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK It would be possible, but it require to know what wiki property is linked to the date ( or date time ) field of the infobox; let me explain with an example:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX time-of-spacecraft-launch: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P619c>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?entity_label, ?property_label, ?time_of_spacecraft_launch WHERE { 
  :Apollo_11 owl:sameAs ?wikidata_entity .
  ?wikidata_entity  time-of-spacecraft-launch: ?time_of_spacecraft_launch .
  ?wikidata_entity  rdfs:label ?entity_label . 
  ?wke_prop ?property_rel time-of-spacecraft-launch:.
  ?wke_prop rdfs:label ?property_label .
  FILTER (LANG(?property_label)='en' && LANG(?entity_label)='it')
}
```

[click here to se the result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FP619c%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fentity_label%2C+%3Fproperty_label%2C+%3Ftime_of_spacecraft_launch+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3AApollo_11+owl%3AsameAs+%3Fwikidata_entity+.%0D%0A++%3Fwikidata_entity++time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A+%3Ftime_of_spacecraft_launch+.%0D%0A++%3Fwikidata_entity++rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fentity_label+.+%0D%0A++%3Fwke_prop+%3Fproperty_rel+time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A.%0D%0A++%3Fwke_prop+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fproperty_label+.%0D%0A++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Fproperty_label%29%3D%27en%27+%26%26+LANG%28%3Fentity_label%29%3D%27it%27%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Now we can gel all the article with the same kind of information simply by removing the where condition on Apollo_11:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX time-of-spacecraft-launch: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P619c>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?entity_label, ?property_label, ?time_of_spacecraft_launch WHERE { 
  ?wikidata_entity  time-of-spacecraft-launch: ?time_of_spacecraft_launch .
  ?wikidata_entity  rdfs:label ?entity_label . 
  ?wke_prop ?property_rel time-of-spacecraft-launch:.
  ?wke_prop rdfs:label ?property_label .
  FILTER (LANG(?property_label)='en' && LANG(?entity_label)='it')
}
```

[see the result here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FP619c%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fentity_label%2C+%3Fproperty_label%2C+%3Ftime_of_spacecraft_launch+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fwikidata_entity++time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A+%3Ftime_of_spacecraft_launch+.%0D%0A++%3Fwikidata_entity++rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fentity_label+.+%0D%0A++%3Fwke_prop+%3Fproperty_rel+time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A.%0D%0A++%3Fwke_prop+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fproperty_label+.%0D%0A++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Fproperty_label%29%3D%27en%27+%26%26+LANG%28%3Fentity_label%29%3D%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)fy

in some cases may be useful to simplify the query:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX time-of-spacecraft-launch: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P619c>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?wikidata_entity  time-of-spacecraft-launch: ?time_of_spacecraft_launch .
  ?wikidata_entity  rdfs:label ?entity_label . 
  FILTER (LANG(?entity_label)='en')
}
ORDER BY DESC(?time_of_spacecraft_launch)
```

[see the result here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FP619c%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+*+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fwikidata_entity++time-of-spacecraft-launch%3A+%3Ftime_of_spacecraft_launch+.%0D%0A++%3Fwikidata_entity++rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fentity_label+.+%0D%0A++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Fentity_label%29%3D%27en%27%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+DESC%28%3Ftime_of_spacecraft_launch%29&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)